# Why is $\int_0^1\left[\nabla^2f(x+td)-\nabla^2f(x)\right]d\;dt=\mathcal o\left(\left\|d\right\|\right)$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and $x\in\mathbb R^n$. By the mean value theorem, $$\nabla f(x+d)=\nabla f(x)+\nabla^2f(x)d+\underbrace{\int_0^1\nabla^2f(x+td)-\nabla^2f(x)\;dt}_{=:\;I(d)}\;d\;\;\;\text{for all }d\in\mathbb R^n\;.$$ I've read, that since $\nabla f$ is continuous (I assume they mean $\nabla^2f$ instead), $$\left\|I(d)d\right\|=\mathcal o\left(\left\|d\right\|\right)\;.\tag{1}$$ I assume, that the $\mathcal o$-notation is with respect to $\left\|d\right\|\to 0$, but I may be wrong. However, I'm unable to prove $(1)$. We would need to show, that $$\lim_{\left\|d\right\|\to 0}\frac{\left\|I(d)d\right\|}{\left\|d\right\|}=0\;,$$ but that seems to be wrong. Clearly, $t\mapsto\nabla^2f(x+td)$ is continuous and hence bounded on the compact set $[0,1]$. But the explicit bound depends on $d$, i.e. we only have $$\left\|I(d)\right\|\le C(d)\;\;\;\text{for all }d\in\mathbb R^n\;,$$ for some $C(d)>0$.

---

Another approach would be, to use the consistency of the norm to obtain $$\frac{\left\|I(d)d\right\|}{\left\|d\right\|}\le\frac{\left\|I(d)\right\|\left\|d\right\|}{\left\|d\right\|}=\left\|I(d)\right\|\stackrel{\Delta\text{-inequality}}{\le}\int_0^1\left\|\nabla^2f(x+td)-\nabla^2f(x)\right\|dt\;.\tag{2}$$ Since $\left\|d\right\|\to 0$ implies $d\to 0$, it follows from the continuity of $\nabla^2f$, that $$\left\|\nabla^2f(x+td)-\nabla^2f(x)\right\|\to 0\;\;\;\text{for }\left\|d\right\|\to 0\;.\tag{3}$$ Do $(2)$ and $(3)$ together build the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the function $$g(t,d)=\left\|\nabla^2f(x+td)-\nabla^2f(x)\right\|$$ be defined on $[0,1]\times\Bbb R^d$. Clearly, it is a continuous function.

From continuity of $\nabla^2 f$ we know that $\forall t\in[0,1]$ we have $\lim_{d\to 0}g(t,d)=0$.

Moreover, form the same continuity we can say that $g(t,d)$ on a compact set $[0,1]\times \{\|d\|\le 1\}$ is bounded by $2\sup_{\|y-x\|\le 1} \|\nabla^2f(y)\|$.

Therefore, by Lebesgue theorem (dominated convergence theorem) $$\lim_{d\to 0}\int_0^1 g(t,d)dt=0,$$
and hence $I(d)d=o(d)$.

Comment: Is my approach ($(2)$ and $(3)$) wrong?

Comment: @0xbadf00d no, your approach was correct. You needed only the uniform integrable majorant to conclude.